# How to perform matrix vector multiplication in Java JOML library?

Tags: java, matrix, graphics, lwjgl

Say I have a 4 by 4 matrix called Matrix4f mat4 and a 1 by 4 vector called Vector4f vec4. I want to porform a matrix vector multiplication say mat4*Transpose(vec4). However, the JOML library does not seem to support this? Can someone suggest a work around? Thanks a lot for your help.

link to joml library: https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Matrix4f.html

Answer (score 0):

The Vector4f class has a [method](https://joml-ci.github.io/JOML/apidocs/org/joml/Vector4f.html#mul-org.joml.Matrix4fc-) to multiply with a matrix.